Darlington NPN preregulator for LDO step down 42v to 12v ~ transistors keep blowing up
this is a follow-up from the original post about this circuit which can be found here. the purpose of this circuit is to reduce the voltage to a lower level that is more palatable for the LDO. and it must be efficient since this was used in a battery management system. the problem however is that any time a external capacitor is connected on the main battery power lines (42v) the 2 transistors in parallel start to get hot and sometimes the plus and minus output is shorted. does anyone know how to fix this or improve this circuit? the output of this citcuit will be connected to a input of a LDO and then voltage will be converted to 3.3v.

My theory on why they start to get hot is that when the capacitor gets connected (1000uf 62v) it causes a voltage dip that destroys the stm32 microcontroller and thus shorts the plus and minus and thats why the transistors start to get hot. im not sure though. thanks..

Any sort of linear regulator and "efficient" are typically opposing concepts. Unless you're supplying milli- or micro-amps then "efficient" demands that you use a switching buck regulator rather than something which just turns electrical energy into heat.

@brhans Yes im aware, this design was from a commercial bms and im trying to use it for the same purpose. there will be bursts of 10mA every 4 seconds so i think it is going to be fine. what do you think is a switcher better here? it will be running all the time what is the quiescent current like? i don't want something expensive or obscure.

(42-11.6)*0.01 = 304 mW. Your Darlingstons won’t share current. Can one of them dissipate 300+ mW? For your blown transistors, I suspect not. You need a buck converter.

”when the capacitor gets connected” No capacitor in your schematic. Please update.


and it must be efficient

There is no more or less efficient when lowering a voltage with a linear regulator, with or without linear components added to offload some of the voltage drop.
Dropping from 42 volts down to (ultimately) 3.3 V will always mean that your linear regulator (with extra components) will turn much more of your power into heat than deliver to your target circuit. Your ultimate efficiency will never be more than 7.86%.
Dropping from 42 volts down to 12 V with a linear regulator will never be more than 28.6% efficient.
If you want efficiency, you must use a switching converter for this job.
If you want to use the circuit you have, or something similar, you will generate heat, and the only way to keep your components cool in that case is with heat-sinking, either passive heat sinking or with something more fancy, like heat pipes or Peltier devices or even a fan.
